# How is the anchor tag created when editing link with Glass Mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper, links

I'm using Sitecore MVC with Glass Mapper.

When I'm creating a component with a link field, I just add 
          `@Editable(myLink, x=> x.myLinkField)`

After setting the links properly on Experience Editor and publishing, it automatically creates the anchor tag with the specified url, class, etc.

I'm wondering where exactly application is creating those attributes and tag. Is this the work of Glass Mapper or any other code?

Comment: Glass mapper uses Sitecore RenderField functionality in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally glass is using sitecore APIs only. If you want to have a look at the exact code then check the **GlassView** class under **Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc** namespace,using any decompiler, in that you will find all the editable methods which internally make a call to Editable method of **GlassHtml** class under **Glass.Mapper.Sc** namespace.

You can find the final code in **BeginRenderLink** method of **GlassHtml** class only. The **BeginRenderLink** is creating anchor tag for you when you use the Editable method for link field.

Comment: As I've looked into the code, this is part of what I'm looking for! thanks for this! Though I'm not using BeginRenderLink, or RenderLink methods I saw, I'm just using the @Editable(myLink, x=> x.myLinkField). How does that create the anchor tag?

Comment: Yes, as I said, at the end it is calling BeginRenderLink only. All editable methods are making call to "MakeEditable" method of GlassHtml class. The "MakeEditable" method checks the field type and if it is link then it will make call to "BeginRenderLink".